# What is the name of this electronic component

Tags: components

I'm trying to attach certain components to my prototype board. However they have short pins, so it is hard to wire-wrap to them. Someone showed me something that you can insert the pins into to make them longer. They come in strips which can be divided. He called it something that sounded like "borgstrip", but that's not what it is. What is it called?

Comment: Berg are a manufacturers of header strips, so it was probably "Berg Strip"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.houseofconnectors.com/berg-strip.htm

Comment: Is that anything different from the usual 0.1" connectors you can find on every PC mainboard?

Comment: They are the same.  These are the extremely common "headers".  0.1" centers, 0.025" square.  Lots of vendors sell them, but prices vary by about 10dB.

Comment: Photo at  https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMmlo.jpg